# How to write a class to return textbox control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I write a class for something like this

Example: I have a `form` that has a panel on it. That panel has an tabbed control. In that tabbed control there is a `textbox`. If I pass the `form` as the start control and “textbox1” [the name of the `TextBox`], the class will return the `texbox` control as a control. This is using c#, asp.net.

So in a form load event, I should be able to do this search as follows:

```
Control txtCtrl = Search.FindControl(“textbox1”, this);
```

Comment: `the class will return the texbox control as a control` Classes don't return anything, methods do.

Comment: Why are you wrapping around FindControl? What are you going to do with your new implementation that FindControl doesn't do already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
class Search
{
    public static TextBox FindControl(string controlToFind, Page page)
    {
         //find your text box
    } 
}
```

As @i4v mentioned, a class does not return anything but you could add a function that will return something.  That being said, this seems like an odd requirement.  Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am just trying to clear some concepts and found this question in a blog written by someone. Since i did not understand, i thought i will throw this out at Gurus!

Comment: You came to the right place! That being said, I think that a class with it's own function is probably overkill for what you are doing.  Personally i would just use Control.FindControl which does most of what you want. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a little cleaner by calling a method that receive the id of the control to find and the control where you want to search. Something like:

```
public class ControlUtils
{
    public static Control FindControl(string idToFind, Control mainControl)
    {
         //Recursively search for the control?
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you. `parentControl` is the container that has the `Textbox` you are looking for.

```
 public TextBox FindTextbox(string name)
 {
     foreach (Control item in parentControl.Children) //based on parent type it my be .Childern, .Items , ...
     {
         if (item is TextBox)
         {
             TextBox temp = item as TextBox;
             if (temp.Name == name)
             {
                 return temp;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```